# How to create an array from $_SESSION elements?

Tags: php, arrays, session

```
$_SESSION['allCaps']=array("Calendar.png", "CD.png", "Chain.png");
```

On next page, I need shuffle these elements, but not the $_SESSION itself.
So, how can I reverse the process:

```
$array = elements_from_$_SESSION['allCaps']  // Calendar.png...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = $_SESSION['allCaps'];
shuffle($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $array = $_SESSION['allCaps']; 
    shuffle($array);
```